# Menu in the top bar won't stay opened when clicked

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d, menu

The menu in the top bar (i believe it's called global menu or application menu, not sure) opens when I press mouse button on it, but immediately closes when I release it. This makes it hard to use, because I have to keep the mouse button pressed all the time I navigate the menu.

How do I switch the behaviour so the menu stays opened when I click it?

Also, this weird behaviour started some time ago, it wasn't always like that. I don't know what triggered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that removing and installing back the `indicator-appmenu` package fixed this problem.